# Subscribe to observable after dispose

Tags: android, rx-java

i am building my app on android [repository by Fernando Cejas](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) and i have a problem with subscribing to observable after calling `dispose`.

When i come to dashboard, i call method `subscribeOnUserMessages.execute(new Subscriber(), new Params(token))`, which is method in `UseCase` class

```
public void execute(DisposableObserver<T> observer, Params params) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(observer);
    final Observable<T> observable = this.buildUseCaseObservable(params)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
            .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());
    addDisposable(observable.subscribeWith(observer));
}
```

In child class `SubscribeOnUserMessages` i simply call repository like this
`return messageRepository.subscribeOnUserMessages(params);`

In my socket implementation i create like this

```
return Observable.create(emitter -> {

        if (!isThereInternetConnection()) {
            Timber.w("Network connection exception");
            emitter.onError(new NetworkConnectionException());
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Open socket if not opened
         */
        openSocket(params.getToken());



        String channelName = CHANNEL_PRIVATE_USER + params.getAuthenticated().getUuid();

        if (subscribedChannels.contains(channelName)) {
            Timber.d("Channel %s is already subscribed", channelName);
            return;
        }


        JSONObject auth;

        try {
            auth = createAuthJson(CHANNEL, channelName, params.getToken());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Timber.e("Couldn't create auth json");
            emitter.onError(e);
            return;
        }

        mSocket.emit(SUBSCRIBE, auth);
        Timber.d("Emitted subscribe with channel: %s ", CHANNEL_PRIVATE_USER + params.getAuthenticated().getUuid());
        subscribedChannels.add(CHANNEL_PRIVATE_USER + params.getAuthenticated().getUuid());
        Timber.d("Subscribing on event: %s\n with user: %s", EVENT_USER_NEW_MESSAGE, params.getAuthenticated().getUuid());

        if (mSocket.hasListeners(EVENT_USER_NEW_MESSAGE)) {
            Timber.v("Socket already has listener on event: %s", EVENT_USER_NEW_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }


        mSocket.on(EVENT_USER_NEW_MESSAGE, args -> {
            if (args[1] == null) {
                emitter.onError(new EmptyResponseException());
            }

            Timber.d("Event - %s %s", EVENT_USER_NEW_MESSAGE, args[1].toString());

            try {
                MessageEntity messageEntity = messageEntityJsonMapper.transform(args[1]);
                emitter.onNext(messageEntity);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Could not parse message json");
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        });

    });
```

Symptoms are that first time i subscribe everything is going through to presentation layer. When i dispose after going to second screen and come back i only see logs coming to socket implementation, but not going through.

My question is: Is there a method for subscribing to same observable again? I've already tried to save that observable in my use case in singleton and subscribe to that observable, didn't help.

Comment: simply invoke `.subscribe()` again to the observable object.

Comment: Define your subscribe to the same observable again? Is it a hot Observable or not? What result you want to see if you subscribe to it again?

Comment: `SocketImpl` is singleton object, that is responsible for getting messages from sockets.

Comment: @PhoenixWang `SocketImpl` is singleton object, that is responsible for getting messages from sockets. It starts listening to socket after subscribing, so it's cold observable. 
The whole case is that, i am on one screen (dashboard) subscribed to messages, then i go to specific chat, so i dispose that subscribtion. When i come back i want to subscribe again to that observable.

Comment: @SimonHarvan So you mean you want to 'pause' that observable in some cases? Then I suppose you could use a subject to manage the upstream your self.

Comment: @PhoenixWang Sorry, i wasn't clear. I have to dispose that subscribtion, because that activity is going to background and i don't know what will happen to it (Activity). Meanwhile, that observable emits, but i don't care about that, because i am not subscribed to it. Then, when i return to activity i want to subscribe to it again.

Comment: @SimonHarvan You don't care about what it emits means your observable should be hot. Make your observable a singleton and use publish().autoConnect() if you want to remain the connection . or share() if you want to disconnect once you dispose.

Comment: @SimonHarvan Hot/Cold Observable doesn't identified by the time they started.  All Observables should be considered initialised lazily. Hot Observable emit item regardless they have subscribers or not once it started. Cold Observables only emit item when they have subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional info and details regrading socket implementation it is hard to spot the problem exactly, but, from the code you've posted, you don't have dispose logic, so while you might properly call `dispose()` to the `Observable` at the correct lifecycle event, your socket will actually stay open, and it might not got disconnected/closed properly ever.
That might lead to a problems opening and connecting to the socket at the 2nd time, as you might try to reopen already open socket and depends on your internal socket impl that might be a problem.
(I can see in the comment that openSocket if not already opened, but still there might be problem elsewhere calling some method on the socket multiple times or setting listeners, again depends on the socket impl)

As a general guidelines, you should add dispose logic using `emitter.setCancellable()`/`emitter.setDisposable()` in order to dispose properly the socket resources when you no longer need them, thus - when applying subscribe again (whether the same object or not) will invoke your subscription logic again that will reopen the socket and listen to it.

It is not clear to me if you like to keep the socket open when you moving to a different screen (I don't think it is a good practice, as you will keep this resource open and might never get back to the screen again to use it), but if that's the case as @Phoenix Wang mentioned, you can use publish kind operators to multicast the `Observable`, so every new `Subscriber` will not try to reopen the socket (i.e. invoking the subscription logic) but will just get notify about messages running in the already opened socket.

Comment: i have just tried `emitter.setCancellable()` and `emitter.setDisposable()`, but it would not fall into these methods. Maybe i am somehow not initializing emitter right.

Comment: also tried `observable.doOnDispose()`, but with no luck.

Comment: Did it did not run when you dispose the Observable? Do you have additional operator applied?

Comment: Yes it didn't, when i disposed it. I don't understand second part. Where should i apply addition?

Comment: the second part I mean whether you add some operators to the stream, anyhow, can you post your code? basically you need to set one of them (as one overrides the other) make sure that the set is called as expected when the create run (you can try to put it as first line, and validate it is not applied as part of some callback or something), those are the official methods so it should work.

Comment: You can find parts of code here. There is also `.map` on a way back to SubscribeOnUserMessages.

[link to code](https://gist.github.com/simonharvan/3edf6aae8bda4328b29d3feb5386e7db)